# cannot target .last span's text

Tags: jquery

My php is this

```
echo "<li><a href='report_view.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>ID:(<span class='id'>" . $row['id'] . "</span>) ".$row['date'] ."- [".$row['domain'] . "]</a> <a class='delete'>delete</a></li>";
```

will output something like this:

ID:(1) May 21, 2011, 1:32 pm- [www.website.com... ] delete

When I press delete I want it to take the ID from that li row  which is displayed between span tags with class of id

My Jquery does this:

```
 $('a.delete').click(function () {  
    $(this).parent("li").next("span.id").html()
    alert(this);
    });
```

keeps alerting nothing, should be alerting 1. What am i doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use HTML5 data-* attributes on the delete link:

```
echo "<li><a href='report_view.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'>ID:(<span class='id'>" . $row['id'] . "</span>) ".$row['date'] ."- [".$row['domain'] . "]</a> <a class='delete' data-delete-id='" . $row['id'] . "'>delete</a></li>";
```

and then:

```
$('a.delete').click(function () {  
    var id = $(this).data('delete-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

or if you are using jquery 1.6:

```
$('a.delete').click(function () {  
    var id = $(this).data('deleteId');
    alert(id);
});
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mGYjg/1/) you may try out.